# Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (57)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, node.js

I am getting the error:

> Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (57)

while running `gulp` command.

I have tried deleting `node_modules` folder and re-running `npm install` after running `npm cache clean`. I have tried the highly recommended `npm rebuild node-sass`. But, to no avail.

Version information:

- Ubuntu: 18.04.1
- node: 5.4.0
- npm: 3.3.12
- node-sass:

  - gulp-sass@2.3.2

    - node-sass@3.13.1

Attaching screenshot of the error. Any help/solution would be highly appreciated.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Everything is very much out of date.

Comment: Yes but it is my limitation because this is the code my company is using. I can't change/update versions

Comment: You’re out of luck then. Perhaps try `nvm` to find a version of Node that’s compatible.

Comment: Have you checked the following: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2142 (The official GitHub repository of this specific package with an issue much like yours). Also, from memory I recall having the remove the contents of my node_modules folder and running npm install again (though you might want to backup the node_modules folder)

Comment: None of it worked.. later I ran npm install gulp --g instead of sudo apt install gulp and my project started working :D

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old issue, but I have a different solution than the ones posted here.

I started to face this issue when I updated my npm to the latest version in my Ubuntu 18.04.

So, I rebuilt the node-sass package using the following command:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

And then, the things worked as expected again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node 10 you will have to update node-sass this way:

```
npm update node-sass
```

You can find additional information about this issue here:

https://medium.com/@proustibat/how-to-fix-error-node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-os-x-64-bit-with-c1b3298e4af0

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to fix this error after **upgrading GCC (g++) version to the latests 7.3.1** instead of my previously installed 4.8.5.

Newer gcc supports command line option `-std=c++14` which causes errors on attempt to rebuild node-sass.

So just upgrade it and then you could rebuild it without any errors  with `node rebuild node-sass` as mentioned in another answer.